# Shell script file organisation

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am currently planning on writing a bigger shell script. The script itself consists of many smaller scripts. I want to organize it modular. For example:

```
.
├── mainScript.sh
└── modules
    ├── moduleScript_1.sh
    ├── moduleScript_2.sh
    └── moduleScript_3.sh

1 directory, 4 files
```

The mainScript will import the modules and defines some shared variables. The single modules are designed to be also useable on their own, so that I can run a module from console if I only need it's certain function.

I know that I can "source" the files just like:

```
#! /bin/bash

sharedVariable="share"

source ./module/moduleScript_1.sh
source ./module/moduleScript_2.sh
source ./module/moduleScript_3.sh
```

...but I am worried about scopes and interfering variables or functions.

Is this file structure actually a good practice, or is there a better, more advanced, way to handle bigger scripts with multiple modules?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you ask me, I wouldn't start a *bigger* application with bash. Use a programming language like Python or Perl instead.

Comment: I don't think bash (or sh) are suitable for it..maybe switching to python? or see what this guy did: http://stackoverflow.com/a/739034/1833218

Comment: @hek2mgl He said `perl`! Stone him!! Rape his cactus!

Comment: @arkascha At least Perl is installed by default in all Linux distributions I am aware of.

Comment: @hek2mgl Could it be that that was some 5-10 years ago?

Comment: I don't see how the selected duplicate is comparable to this question, not sure what "Community" has smoked. This question is ok.

Comment: My vote goes for Ruby over perl and Python!